# SQL Server query joins with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, join

I am trying to join two tables using Dates but I want the join to be:

```
table1.date = (table2.date + 1)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to add one day?, but yes, it is possible

Comment: Try it and show us if you get an error.

Comment: I would suggest using DateAdd instead of just math. It works but is confusing and doesn't work with all the date datatypes. https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations

Comment: @Prdp : table1.date = (table2.date + 1) gives an error as Operand type clash : date incompatible with int.

Comment: @DipeshSurana - yeah, It will not work with `date` datatype, it works if it is `datetime`. Use `DATEADD` as mentioned in below answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE `DATEADD` FUNCTION

```
on table1.date = dateadd(dd,1,table2.date)
```